# Can we rely on the data we get from Web API's for measuring the front end performance metrics of a web application?

Tags: performance, testing, automation, frontend, performance-testing

In order to measure and track the front end performance of a web application, can we rely on the data we get from Web Api's mainly - Navigation and performance timeline API. ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, you can.

They are probably one of the most accurate ways of measuring performance as they are built right into the browser and are the basis of a lot of web statistics such as the [CrUX report](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/).

You might want to check out the [Web vitals library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals#send-the-results-to-an-analytics-endpoint) from chrome as it is already built to measure the things that Google believes to be important, namely:

- Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)
- First Input Delay (FID)
- Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)
- First Contentful Paint (FCP)
- Time to First Byte (TTFB)

Comment: Apart from the above metrics, is there any other way or formula to get the below metrics:
1) Time to interaction
2) Page load time
3) Page render time
4) Total blocking time